# Почему по Vue не отображается код на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

```
        <script setup>
        import FirstCol from './components/FirstCol.vue'
        import SecondCol from './components/SecondCol.vue'
        import SupBody from './components/SupBody.vue'
        import tar1 from './components/tar1.vue'
        import tar2 from './components/tar2.vue'
        import comp1 from './components/comp1.vue'
        import comp2 from './components/comp2.vue'
        import comp3 from './components/comp3.vue'
        import team1 from './components/team1.vue'
        import cases from './components/cases.vue'
        
        import tar3 from './components/tar3.vue'
        
        
        
          import 'swiper/css';
        </script>
        
        <script>
        import { ref } from 'vue';
          import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';
          import { Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation } from 'swiper/modules';
        
          import 'swiper/css';
          import 'swiper/css/pagination';
          import 'swiper/css/navigation';
        
          
        export default {
          data() {
            return {
              phone: '',
              name: '',
              email: '',
              message: '',
              consent: false,
              show: true,
              activeIndexes: [],
              items: [
                { question: '1.Кто непосредственно занимается поддержкой?', 
                  answer: 'Поддержка и обслуживание включают в себя команду  программистов и дизайнеров. Эти специалисты отвечают за техническую поддержку, обновления модели, улучшение ее функциональности и обеспечение безопасности и этичности использования.' },
                 
              ]
            };
          },
          methods: {
            phoneinput() {
              this.phone = this.phone.replace(/\D/g, '');
            },
            formbut() {
              if (!this.name || !this.email || !this.phone || !this.message || !this.consent) {
                alert('Пожалуйста, заполните все поля');
                return;
              }
              localStorage.setItem('formValues', JSON.stringify({
                name: this.name,
                email: this.email,
                phone: this.phone,
                message: this.message,
                consent: this.consent
              }));
              this.sendFormData();
              this.name = '';
              this.email = '';
              this.phone = '';
              this.message = '';
              this.consent = false;
              alert('Данные успешно отправлены!');
            },
            sendFormData() {
              const formData = {
                name: this.name,
                email: this.email,
                phone: this.phone,
                message: this.message,
                consent: this.consent
              };
              fetch('https://formcarry.com/s/jpXL8tnTne', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(formData),
              });
            },
            answer(index) {
              const active = this.active(index);
              if (active) {
                this.activeIndexes = this.activeIndexes.filter(i => i !== index);
              } else {
                this.activeIndexes.push(index);
              }
            },
            active(index) {
              return this.activeIndexes.includes(index);
            }
          },
          components: {
              Swiper,
              SwiperSlide,
            },
            setup() {
              const prev = ref(null);
              const next = ref(null);
              const fraction = ref(null);
              return {
                modules: [Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation],
                prev,
                next,
                fraction
              };
            },
            data () {
              return {
                comments: [
                  {
                    brend: 'comment_logo.svg',
                    description: 'Команда Drupal Coder вызвала только положительные впечатления!'
                  },
                  {
                    brend: 'works_card_1.svg',
                    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing.'
                  },
                  {
                    brend: 'works_card_2.svg',
                    description: 'Provident similique accusantium nemo autem.'
                  },
                  {
                    brend: 'works_card_3.svg',
                    description: 'Perspiciatis minima nesciunt dolorem!'
                  },
                  {
                    brend: 'works_card_4.svg',
                    description: 'Commodi minima excepturi repudiandae velit hic maxime doloremque.'
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
        };
        </script>
        
        
        <template>
          <header>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg">
            <div class="container col-lg-12 col-md-12">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="./assets/img/drupal-coder.svg" width="137" height="20" alt="logo"></a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDarkDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDarkDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDarkDropdown">
                
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="comment_container">
              <h1 class="comment_title">
                Отзывы
              </h1>
              <img src="./assets/bg_left.png" alt="" class="bg_left">
              <div class="comment">
                <div class="comment_left">
                  <swiper
                    :pagination="{
                      type: 'fraction',
                      el: fraction
                    }"
                    :navigation="{
                      prevEl: prev,
                      nextEl: next,
                    }"
                    :modules="modules"
                    class="mySwiper"
                  >
                    <swiper-slide v-for="i in comments" :key="i">
                      <div class="comment_card">
                        <img :src="require(`@/assets/${i.brend}`)" alt="">
                        <h6>
                          {{ i.description }}
                        </h6>
                        <p>
                          Нуреев Александр, менеджер проекта Winamp Russian Community
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </swiper-slide>
                  </swiper>
                </div>
          
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="comment_right">
                  <div class="swiper_btns">
                    <button ref="prev" class="swiper-button-prev">
                      <img src="./assets/arrow-left.svg" alt="">
                    </button>
                    <div ref="fraction" class="swiper-pagination-fraction">
                      <span class="">
                        1
                      </span>
                      <span class="number_line">/</span>
                      <span class="swiper-pagination-total">
                        5
                      </span>
                    </div>
                    <button ref="next" class="swiper-button-next">
                      <img src="./assets/arrow-right.svg" alt="">
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          
            <section class="works_card">
              <div class="main_container">
                <h2 class="comment_title">С нами работают</h2>
                <p class="description">Десятки компаний доверяют нам самое ценное, что у них есть в интернете – свои сайты. Мы делаем всё, чтобы наше сотрудничество было долгим.</p>
                <swiper
                  :slidesPerView="'auto'"
                  :loop="true"
                  :spaceBetween="20"
                  :centeredSlides="true"
                  :speed="3000"
                  :autoplay="{
                    delay: 0,
                  }"
                  :modules="modules"
                  class="works_card_slider"
                >
                  <swiper-slide v-for="i in 4" :key="i">
                    <div class="card_content">
                      <img :src="require(`@/assets/works_card_${i}.svg`)" alt="">
                    </div>
                  </swiper-slide>
                  <swiper-slide v-for="i in 4" :key="i">
                    <div class="card_content">
                      <img :src="require(`@/assets/works_card_${i}.svg`)" alt="">
                    </div>
                  </swiper-slide>
                  <swiper-slide v-for="i in 4" :key="i">
                    <div class="card_content">
                      <img :src="require(`@/assets/works_card_${i}.svg`)" alt="">
                    </div>
                  </swiper-slide>
                </swiper>
                <swiper
                  :slidesPerView="'auto'"
                  :loop="true"
                  :centered-slides="true"
                  :spaceBetween="20"
                  :centeredSlides="true"
                  :speed="3000"
                  :autoplay="{
                    delay: 0,
                    reverseDirection: true,
                  }"
                  :modules="modules"
                  class="works_card_slider"
                >
                  <swiper-slide v-for="i in 4" :key="i">
                    <div class="card_content">
                      <img :src="require(`@/assets/works_card_${i}.svg`)" alt="">
                    </div>
                  </swiper-slide>
                  <swiper-slide v-for="i in 4" :key="i">
                    <div class="card_content">
                      <img :src="require(`@/assets/works_card_${i}.svg`)" alt="">
                    </div>
                  </swiper-slide>
                  <swiper-slide v-for="i in 4" :key="i">
                    <div class="card_content">
                      <img :src="require(`@/assets/works_card_${i}.svg`)" alt="">
                    </div>
                  </swiper-slide>
                </swiper>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        <!--FAQ-->
        <div>
             <center> <h2> FAQ</h2></center>
                  <div id="faq" v-if="show">
                <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" class="item" @click="answer(index)" :class="{ 'active': active(index) }">
                  <div class="content" :class="{ 'active': active(index) }">
                    <span class="question">{{ item.question }}</span>
                    <div v-if="active(index)">{{ item.answer }}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <router-view/>
            </div>
        <div class="fon">
            <div class="form">
              <div class="left">
            <p class="otzuv">
                Оставьте заявку на поддержку сайта
            </p>
            
        
        
        </template>
        
        <style>
    
      
    }
        #block-cases .view-content:after {
          content: "";
          display: table;
          clear: both;
        }
        #block-cases .block-title {
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 42px;
          margin-bottom: 46px;
          margin-top: 0;
          text-align: center;
          color: #050c33;
        }
        
        
        .
        
        
 
   color: #050c33;
        }
        .inverse .blog.keys-1:nth-child(4n+1) .keys-date {
          color: #050c33;
        }
        .blog.keys-2 {
          width: 66.66666667%;
          padding: 0 10px;
          float: left;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
          min-height: 475px;
          font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
          overflow: hidden;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        .link{text-decoration: none;text-align: start;}
        
        
        /*Тарифы*/
        .social-icons {
          margin-top: 20px;
          padding-left:18%; 
        }
        .two,.one {
        line-height:5px;
        }
        .two{
          padding-bottom:2%;
        }
        .social-icons i {
          font-size: 24px; 
          color: #F14D34; 
          margin-right: 15px; 
        }
        
        .social-icons i:last-child {
          margin-right: 0;
        }
        .social-icons i:hover {
          color: #D43F22; 
        }
        .fon1 {
          background-color: #090b18;
         
        
        }
        .fon {
          background-color: #090b18;
          width: 100%;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
        }
        .tel{
        margin-top:100px;
        
        }
        .tel,.email
        {
          font-size:30px;
          line-height:10px;
        }
        p
        {
          color:white;
        }
        .form {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
          width: 80%;
          
        }
        .form .left {
          margin-left: 10%; 
        }
        .left {
          width: 480px; 
        }
        
        .right {
          width: calc(100% - 100px); 
          max-width: 400px;
          padding: 20px 0; 
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        .formel {
          margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        
        label {
          color: white;
          display: block;
          margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        
        .formin {
          width: 100%;
          padding: 8px;
          font-size: 15px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          background-color: #090b18;
          color: white;
          border: 1px solid white;
          border-radius: 3px;
          height: 50px;
        }
        
        textarea.formin {
          resize: vertical;
          border-radius: 3px;
          height: 100px; 
        }
        
        .orbutton {
          width: 100%;
          height:45px;
          padding: 10px;
          background-color: #F14D34; ;
          color: white;
          border: none;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .consent-group {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
        }
        
        .galka {
          margin-left: 5px;
          color: white;
        }
        
        .otzuv {
          color: white;
          margin-bottom: 5px;
          font-size:40px;
        }
        .line {
            background-color: gray;
            height: 2px;
            width: 100%;
          }
          /*FAQ */
          #faq {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
          }
           
          .item {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 60%; 
           
          }
          .question {
            font-weight: bold; 
          }
          .content {
            border: 1px solid #ccc; 
            padding: 10px; 
            text-align: left; 
            transition: background-color 0.3s; 
          }
           
          .content:hover {
            background-color: #f0f0f0; 
          }
           
          .content.active {
            border-color: red; 
            background-color: #ffffff; 
          }
          
          
          @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            template{
              max-width: 100%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
          }
            .form {
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 100%;
          }
        
          .left {
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: 0;
           
          }
        
          .right {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: none;
            padding: 10px;
          }
        
          .formin,
          textarea.formin {
            height: 40px;
          }
        
          .consent-group {
            flex-direction: column;
          }
        
          .orbutton {
            height: 40px;
          }
        
          .social-icons {
            padding-left: 10%;
          }
          .otzuv, .promo {
            padding-right: 50px; }
        
            html, body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        }
             
        }
        
        body {
          font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
          font-style: normal;
        }
        
        * {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        button {
          background: transparent;
          outline: none;
          border: none;
        }
        
        .wrapper {
          width: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        .main_container {
          max-width: 980px;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
        
        .description {
          color: var(--main-black, #050C33);
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 500;
          line-height: 22px;
          opacity: 0.7;
        }
        
        .works_card .description {
          max-width: 740px;
          margin: 0 auto 42px;
        }
        
        .works_card .comment_title {
          margin-bottom: 10px;
          margin-top: 160px;
        }
        
        .works_card_slider {
          overflow: visible;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
          user-select: none;
        }
        
        .works_card_slider:last-child {
          margin-bottom: 160px;
        }
        
        .works_card_slider .swiper-wrapper{
          transition-timing-function:linear;
        }
        
        .works_card_slider .swiper-slide {
          border-radius: 5px;
          border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
          cursor: pointer;
          width: 291px;
        }
        
        .works_card_slider .swiper-slide .card_content {
          height: 155px;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
        }
        
        .swiper_btns{
          width: 206px;
          /* border: 1px solid red; */
          position: relative;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
        }
        
        .swiper-pagination-fraction {
          width: auto;
          text-align: center;
        }
        
        .swiper-pagination-fraction span {
          font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
          font-size: 28px;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 400;
          line-height: 28px;
        }
        
        .swiper-wrapper {
          padding: 5px;
        }
        
        /* .swiper-pagination-current {
          color: #050C33;
        }
        
        .number_line {
          color: #E0E0E0;
        }
        
        .swiper-pagination-total {
          color: #E0E0E0;
        } */
        
        .comment_right {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
        }
        
        .swiper-button-prev {
          position: absolute;
        }
        
        .swiper-button-prev::after {
          display: none;
        }
        .swiper-button-next::after {
          display: none;
        }
        
        .comment_container {
          max-width: 1440px;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .comment_title {
          color: #050C33;
          text-align: center;
          font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
          font-size: 42px;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 700;
          line-height: normal;
          padding-top: 60px;
          margin-bottom: 46px;
        }
        
        .comment {
          padding: 80px 80px 88px 120px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          display: flex;
          max-width: 980px;
          border-radius: 5px;
          border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
          background: #FFF;
          box-shadow: 0px 4px 60px 0px rgba(161, 161, 161, 0.25);
        }
        
        .line {
          margin: 0 60px;
          width: 1px;
          height: auto;
          background: #000;
          opacity: 0.2;
          /* height: 100%; */
        }
        
        .comment_left {
          /* padding-right: 60px; */
          width: 440px;
          position: relative;
        }
        
        .comment_left h6 {
          max-width: 440px;
          margin: 41px 0 28px 0;
          color: #050C33;
          font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
          font-size: 24px;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 700;
          line-height: normal;
          text-decoration-line: underline;
        }
        
        .comment_left p {
          max-width: 380px;
          color: #050C33;
          font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 500;
          line-height: normal;
        }
        
        .bg_left {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          width: 23%;
        }
        
        
        .swiper-pagination-fraction {
          color: #E0E0E0;
          font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
          font-size: 28px;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 400;
          line-height: 28px;
          display: flex;
          gap: 8px;
        }
        
        .swiper-pagination-current {
          color: #050C33;
        }
        
        @media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
          .comment {
            padding: 30px;
            flex-direction: column;
            gap: 30px;
            margin: 0px 20px;
          }
        
          .main_container {
            padding: 0 20px;
          }
        
          .comment_title {
            margin-top: 30px;
            padding-top: 0;
            font-size: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
          }
        
          .comment_left {
            width: 100%;
          }
        
          .comment_left h6  {
            font-size: 20px;
          }
        
          .swiper_btns {
            margin: 0 auto;
          }
        
          .line {
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 1px;
          }
        
          .swiper-pagination-fraction {
            font-size: 20px;
            gap: 8px;
          }
        
          .swiper-pagination-fraction span {
            font-size: 20px;
          }
        }
        
        </style>
    Не отображается код начиная с отзывов, не могу понять в чем проблема. Подскажите пожалуйста
```

Comment: У Вас HTML невалидный, нет закрывающих `header` и `nav` тегов, и еще куча незакрытых `div`, отображается до отзывов, потому что Ваш код обрывается на отзывах.